# Playscape 1.11 SDK integration in unity

Tags: java, android, playscape

During the integration of playscape SDK on unity, when I build the APK to android I get the following error:
An error occured while applying post build logic: ApplicationName="/bin/java.exe" CommandLine="-classpath...."

What did I miss in the integration process? I added an 
[image of the error in unity](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ovrc6sxh5ju6ewd/SDK_error.PNG?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you're seeing is related to the fact that your JAVA_HOME environment variable is not configured on your machine. Please configure it and build the apk again.

Sharon