# Unity Playscape error during post-build on android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, playscape

After making all steps in Playscape "Unity project setup guide" and building to android, post-build error occurs:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYw1E.png

Any ideas what may cause this error?

Comment: can you please verify that your JAVA_HOME is configured correctly. Are you using the correct Java version? (the machine is probably 64 bit so the JDK should also be 64 bit)

Comment: yes Java_home is set to jdk folder, and jdk is 64 bit version 1.8.0_45

Comment: I've talked with one of the developers and we're pretty sure it's related to the JAVE_HOME not configured correctly. Can you please contact me directly at sharonh@playscape.com

Comment: This question was already answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31518497/playscape-1-11-sdk-integration-in-unity

Comment: Thank You for help. I needed to set JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME for everything to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to set JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME for everything to work.